# Sharing values between kinect class and opentk onrenderframe class

Tags: c#, kinect, opentk

I use Kinect and `OpenTK` in my application. In one class I use `WindowLoaded` method, which in loop calls `SensorSkeletonFrameReady` and write to console computed coordinates of right hand.

In main window class I call `OnRenderFrame`, which in loop draws cube to viewport.

So basically I need to send coordinates from `SensorSkeletonFrameReady` in kinectControl to `OnRenderFrame` in main window class.

I tried accomplish this with thread, but I don't know how to send values.

Edit:

This is mainwindow class:

```
                ...
                public class MainWindow : GameWindow
                {
                ...
                /*Kinect thread start*/
                        kinectControl kinectObject = new kinectControl();
                        Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(kinectObject.WindowLoaded));
                        oThread.Start();
                        ...
protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
        {
        ...
        //Here I need get coordinates from kinectControl

                        DrawCube();
                        ...
```

And this is kinectControl class:

```
    ...
    private void SensorSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
    ...
            foreach (Skeleton skeleton in skeletons)
            {
                Joint rightHand = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandRight];
                Joint leftHand = skeleton.Joints[JointType.HandLeft];
                Joint head = skeleton.Joints[JointType.Head];

                double leftY = leftHand.Position.Y;
                double headY = head.Position.Y;




                // get the individual points of the right hand
                double rightX = rightHand.Position.X;
                double rightY = rightHand.Position.Y;
                double rightZ = rightHand.Position.Z;

                //here I need send this coordinates to mainwindow class
```

...

Edit2: I found solution, instead of registering event, I use polling with OpenNextFrame method in OnRenderFrame Method.

```
public void findSkeleton()//random name of function
        {
            Skeleton[] skeletons = new Skeleton[0];

            SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = this.sensor.SkeletonStream.OpenNextFrame(0);

                if (skeletonFrame != null)
                {
                    skeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
                    skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);
                }
...//rest is the same as in SensorSkeletonFrameReady event
```

Comment: Can you please post the applicable code that you are talking about here?  Having `SensorSkeletonFrameReady` in a loop doesn't make sense -- that is an event.  You can be tracking the `SensorSkeletonFrameReady` event in the same class as your `OnRenderFrame`.  Having some code to see your logic will help understand your end goals.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is event not loop, I was wrong.

Comment: My short answer is that the Kinect processing does not need to be in its own Thread.  Have a look at all the samples in the Kinect for Windows Toolkit -- none use a thread, because all the processing is already done outside the UI thread; the events allow you to capture the information and process it on the UI thread.  I'll get a more detailed answer together soon.

Answer (score 0):

Polling is an option, but it is still not clear to me the necessity put the Kinect code in a separate thread.  All polling and processing done by the Kinect are already done off the UI thread, it is only when you capture one of the `FrameReady` events that you bring the UI thread into the mix.  When capturing that event you are generally wanting to do something with the UI anyway.

Personally, I use the follow core structure to

```
private readonly KinectSensorChooser _sensorChooser = new KinectSensorChooser();

public MainViewModel()
{
    KinectSensorManager = new KinectSensorManager();
    KinectSensorManager.KinectSensorChanged += OnKinectSensorChanged;

    _sensorChooser.Start();

    if (_sensorChooser.Kinect == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to detect an available Kinect Sensor");
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }

    // Bind the KinectSensor from the sensorChooser to the KinectSensor on the KinectSensorManager
    var kinectSensorBinding = new Binding("Kinect") { Source = _sensorChooser };
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.KinectSensorManager, KinectSensorManager.KinectSensorProperty, kinectSensorBinding);
}
```

The `KinectSensorManager` is a helper function found in the `KinectWpfViewers` example project; part of the Kinect for Windows Toolkit.  Using the above my Kinect is then initialized with the following:

```
#region Kinect Discovery & Setup

private void OnKinectSensorChanged(object sender, KinectSensorManagerEventArgs<KinectSensor> args)
{
    if (null != args.OldValue)
        UninitializeKinectServices(args.OldValue);

    if (null != args.NewValue)
        InitializeKinectServices(KinectSensorManager, args.NewValue);
}

/// <summary>
/// Initialize Kinect based services.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="kinectSensorManager"></param>
/// <param name="sensor"></param>
private void InitializeKinectServices(KinectSensorManager kinectSensorManager, KinectSensor sensor)
{
    // configure the color stream
    kinectSensorManager.ColorFormat = ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30;
    kinectSensorManager.ColorStreamEnabled = true;

    // configure the depth stream
    kinectSensorManager.DepthStreamEnabled = true;

    kinectSensorManager.TransformSmoothParameters =
        new TransformSmoothParameters
        {
            // as the smoothing value is increased responsiveness to the raw data
            // decreases; therefore, increased smoothing leads to increased latency.
            Smoothing = 0.5f,
            // higher value corrects toward the raw data more quickly,
            // a lower value corrects more slowly and appears smoother.
            Correction = 0.5f,
            // number of frames to predict into the future.
            Prediction = 0.5f,
            // determines how aggressively to remove jitter from the raw data.
            JitterRadius = 0.05f,
            // maximum radius (in meters) that filtered positions can deviate from raw data.
            MaxDeviationRadius = 0.04f
        };

    // configure the skeleton stream
    sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += OnSkeletonFrameReady;
    kinectSensorManager.SkeletonStreamEnabled = true;

    // initialize the gesture recognizer
    _gestureController = new GestureController();
    _gestureController.GestureRecognized += OnGestureRecognized;

    kinectSensorManager.KinectSensorEnabled = true;

    if (!kinectSensorManager.KinectSensorAppConflict)
    {
        // more initialization
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Uninitialize all Kinect services that were initialized in InitializeKinectServices.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sensor"></param>
private void UninitializeKinectServices(KinectSensor sensor)
{
    // unregister services
}
```

In my examples code here I have a `SkeletonFrameReady` event defined.  This would be the same for any of the other `FrameReady` events.  You can set up the appropriate handler to get the data and then do what you need to do with it.  You're now in the main class where your OpenTK references are.

The only thing happening on the UI thread is what is inside your handler function, or what it calls.